# Mongodb Compass find id in array property of object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

sorry, really simple question. I have a mongo collection and it's documents have a property that is an array of ObjectId's

```
projects
{
 admins:[ObjectId('1'),ObjectId('2'),ObjectId('3')]
}
```

Using compass filters, How do i get all documents that have a certain ID in the admin array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter by one id.

```
{ admins: ObjectId('2') }
```

Or if you want to filter by using multiple admin's ids using `$in`:

```
{ admins: { $in: [ ObjectId('1'), ObjectId('2') ] } }
```